# Laravel jsonb columns encoded as string in javascript object

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

My Laravel API is sending `user` data this way:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function user(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->user()->only([
            'email',
            'foo',
            'bar'
        ]);
    }
```

When I get it with Nuxt auth module, the `jsonb` columns `foo` and `bar` are encoded as a string, in quotes, in my `state.auth.user` object.

Can I fix it on Laravel side ? If yes, how ?

Nuxt `pages/index.js`:

```
async login() {
  await this.$auth
    .loginWith('laravelPassport', {
      data: {
        username: this.email,
        password: '1qaz@WSX'
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by casting these columns to `array` in my `User` model:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'foo' => 'array',
    'bar' => 'array'
];
```